# Autocompletion using TAB key on solaris machine

Tags: shell, autocomplete, solaris

I am currently facing some problem with "tab key autocompletion" feature in my Solaris tcsh shell.

I have multiple users logged in our solaris server. Except for one particular user, all other users are able to use tab key for autocompletion of commands etc.

I tried searching the forum, but found no useful solution for me.

Any clues?

Thanks
Deepak

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98578/freebsd-csh-tab-to-show-available-choices  Oh yeah, this too:  http://www.perl.com/doc/FMTEYEWTK/versus/csh.whynot

Comment: https://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-questions/2005-January/072476.html

Answer (score 1):

This fixed my Solaris 10:

```
>tcsh
>set autolist
```

<kbd>TAB</kbd> should work from there on in your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

For ksh on Solaris, there seem to be a few postings to suggest different things.

- Using [pdksh](http://web.cs.mun.ca/~michael/pdksh/) - `set -o vi-tabcomplete`
- Using ksh-93 - `set -o viraw`
- Put in vi mode with `set -o vi`, and instead of tab use: <kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>\</kbd>, <kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>*</kbd>, and <kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>=</kbd>
- Using tcsh - `set autolist`
- Use bash

References:

- https://superuser.com/q/65964
- [How to autocomplete at the KornShell command line with the vi editor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/81022/744133) (AIX, but works for solaris)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/98578/117221 (tcsh/csh, freebsd, but works on solaris)